How to create harness pipeline to deploy app in EC2?
I want to create a simple pipeline in Harness that will deploy my simple application to AWS EC2.
I've already made my Harness listen to the GitHub repository where the application code is stored in JS.
I also added my secret key from the AWS account to the Harness secrets, as well as the pem that I use to SSH into my EC2 instance.
I've found an example of how this can be done, but there are a lot of things that are quite complicated.

If you're looking to deploy to an EC2 instance, please refer to this documentation: Deploying to AWS with Auto Scaling Groups. Alternatively, if you prefer deploying using a virtual machine(VM) on an AWS instance, please consult this documentation: Deploying to a VM on an AWS instance with SSH. Let me know if you have any questions!
